# Phrase for events/experiences that don't seem significant when you retrospect

Tags: phrase-requests

The question popped up in my mind when I got a vacation after almost 3 years and I had a chance to retrospect. In a broad sense, I have the following classification of experiences:
The cherished memories, the significant events:

- The times spent with the fast friends
- Excursions in Nature
- Books and travel

(Now) Insignificant, barely recallable events:

- Visiting plush restaurants and hanging out with people who were sort of 'temporary'
- Unpleasant situations at the workplace
- Worrying about petty problems and outcomes

What phrases can I use to tersely describe these two sets of experiences e.g: Suppose I try to pen down what I have written above (the types of experiences):
When I retrospect the past 3 decades of my life, I had two sets of experiences - |phrase for set-1, the ones that are sort of 'permanent'| and |phrase for set-2, they came as per the changes in the age but haven't lasted longer to become a memory or make a difference|.

I apologize if the question sounds vague but haven't been able to pen my thoughts precisely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

experiences of **permanence** ... and  those of **ephemerality**

**permanence**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/permanence)

> The quality or condition of being permanent; permanency.

**ephemeral**

> Lasting for a markedly brief time:

Answer (score 1):

Retrospect as a verb is so rare it doesn’t show up in a * retrospect Google NGram search.